# Transact SQL: ISNULL returning null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in my SQL Server 2017:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sync_versions](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_device_type] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [version_stamp] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [update_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sync_versions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sync_versions] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [update_date]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sync_versions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_sync_versions_device_type] FOREIGN KEY([id_device_type])
REFERENCES [dbo].[device_types] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sync_versions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_sync_versions_device_type]
GO
```

The table currently contains no data. However, the following query returns nothing.

```
select isnull([version_stamp],'0x0000000000000001') as [version_stamp]
from [dbo].[sync_versions]
where [id_device_type] = 2;
```

I expected this query to return `0x0000000000000001`, am I wrong? If so, is there any alternate method of returning a default value if the table contains no data?

Kind regards.

Comment: If the table contains no data you'll get no rows, not even NULL. That's how SQL works, not a SQL Server peculiarity. Why do you want to change what's returned? How are you going to differentiate actual NULLs from no results?

Comment: `NULL` is still a value; just an unknown one. As such the absence of any values is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: As for `version_stamp` what are you trying to do? SQL Server has a [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type to handle optimistic concurrency scenarios and [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to find rows changed since a previous version. Change tracking can handle deletions too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If table contains no data, you will receive 0 rows. So, you need to wrap you query:

```
ISNULL(
    (select [version_stamp]
    from [dbo].[sync_versions]
    where [id_device_type] = 2),
'0x0000000000000001')
```

Comment: You have a duplicated `'`, also I need to put `(` and `)` around the SELECT for this to work.

Comment: It's safer to leave out the `top 1`. If for whatever reason there are multiple matching rows, that will cause the query to error out, rather than select an arbitrary row. Neither behavior is an exact match for the original (which would return multiple rows), but failing loudly by default is safer than failing silently.

Comment: @JeroenMostert make sense